# Keras Efficientnet B0 use input values between 0 and 255

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, imagenet, efficientnet

I am using a EfficientNet B0 from keras application.

```
tf.keras.applications.EfficientNetB0(include_top=True,weights=None,input_tensor=None, input_shape=(224, 224, 6), pooling=None,classes=5,classifier_activation="softmax")
```

Keras thereby normalizes the input to (0,1). I found the following line in the keras code:

```
x = layers.Rescaling(1. / 255.)(x)
```

Now I do not want to to rescale the input. As input I want to use the original image, because I work with a coral edgetpu board. This board only works fast with int8.
I just want to remove the line above.
I could copy the code from keras in my project.
But then it doesn't work anymore when I use a different version of Tensorflow.
Does anyone have an idea?

I am using Tensorflow 2.4

Comment: You could just multiply your inputs by 255

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But I use training aware quantization. And the Rescale Layer is not supported with training aware quantization. I tried to use quantization after the training but the performance was bad.